# Alamofire wont build with latest code

Tags: alamofire

I am on XCode 6.4. I tried both adding the project via GIT and CocoaPods.

Both ways XCode fails to build with 100s of errors and warnings.

Anyone else seeing this behavior?

Examples:

```
/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:88:5: Extraneous '_' in parameter: 'URLString' has no keyword argument name

/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:120:5: Extraneous '_' in parameter: 'URLString' has no keyword argument name

/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:164:5: Extraneous '_' in parameter: 'URLString' has no keyword argument name

/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:198:5: Extraneous '_' in parameter: 'URLString' has no keyword argument name

/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:232:5: Extraneous '_' in parameter: 'URLString' has no keyword argument name

/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:267:5: Extraneous '_' in parameter: 'URLString' has no keyword argument name

/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:324:5: Extraneous '_' in parameter: 'URLString' has no keyword argument name

/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Download.swift:147:9: 'directory directory' can be expressed more succinctly as '#directory'

/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Download.swift:200:24: Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'

/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Download.swift:201:19: Expected 'while' in 'do-while' loop

/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Download.swift:201:25: Braced block of statements is an unused closure

/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Manager.swift:135:18: Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'

/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Manager.swift:135:40: Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'

/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Manager.swift:135:41: Expected expression

/Pods/Alamofire/Source/MultipartFormData.swift:62:34: 'boundaryType boundaryType' can be expressed more succinctly as '#boundaryType'

/Pods/Alamofire/Source/MultipartFormData.swift:141:32: 'data data' can be expressed more succinctly as '#data'

/Pods/Alamofire/Source/MultipartFormData.swift:163:32: 'data data' can be expressed more succinctly as '#data'

/Pods/Alamofire/Source/MultipartFormData.swift:186:32: 'data data' can be expressed more succinctly as '#data'

/Pods/Alamofire/Source/MultipartFormData.swift:211:32: 'fileURL fileURL' can be expressed more succinctly as '#fileURL'

/Pods/Alamofire/Source/MultipartFormData.swift:239:32: 'fileURL fileURL' can be expressed more succinctly as '#fileURL'

/Pods/Alamofire/Source/MultipartFormData.swift:246:14: Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'

/Pods/Alamofire/Source/MultipartFormData.swift:246:30: Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'

/Pods/Alamofire/Source/MultipartFormData.swift:246:31: Expected expression

/Pods/Alamofire/Source/MultipartFormData.swift:246:36: Braced block of statements is an unused closure

/Pods/Alamofire/Source/MultipartFormData.swift:259:12: Expected expression, var, or let in 'if' condition

/Pods/Alamofire/Source/MultipartFormData.swift:259:37: Braced block of statements is an unused closure

/Pods/Alamofire/Source/MultipartFormData.swift:263:14: Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'

/Pods/Alamofire/Source/MultipartFormData.swift:263:26: Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'

/Pods/Alamofire/Source/MultipartFormData.swift:263:27: Expected expression

/Pods/Alamofire/Source/MultipartFormData.swift:263:32: Braced block of statements is an unused closure

/Pods/Alamofire/Source/MultipartFormData.swift:275:14: Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'

/Pods/Alamofire/Source/MultipartFormData.swift:277:13: Expected expression

/Pods/Alamofire/Source/MultipartFormData.swift:278:9: Braced block of statements is an unused closure

/Pods/Alamofire/Source/MultipartFormData.swift:294:32: Expected '{' after 'if' condition

/Pods/Alamofire/Source/MultipartFormData.swift:295:13: Braced block of statements is an unused closure

/Pods/Alamofire/Source/MultipartFormData.swift:298:11: Expected 'while' in 'do-while' loop

/Pods/Alamofire/Source/MultipartFormData.swift:298:17: Braced block of statements is an unused closure

/Pods/Alamofire/Source/MultipartFormData.swift:302:14: Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'

/Pods/Alamofire/Source/MultipartFormData.swift:302:45: Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'

/Pods/Alamofire/Source/MultipartFormData.swift:302:46: Expected expression

/Pods/Alamofire/Source/MultipartFormData.swift:302:51: Braced block of statements is an unused closure

/Pods/Alamofire/Source/MultipartFormData.swift:313:14: Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'

/Pods/Alamofire/Source/MultipartFormData.swift:313:55: Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'

/Pods/Alamofire/Source/MultipartFormData.swift:313:56: Expected expression

/Pods/Alamofire/Source/MultipartFormData.swift:313:61: Braced block of statements is an unused closure
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you are probably following the directions listed on the main Github page and are using `~> 2.0` in your `Podfile`. If you look at the [requirements](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/README.md#requirements), you'll see that it require Xcode 7.0+ among other things. My suggestion is to specify an older version like `~> 1.3` for use with your project in your Podfile. You could download the 7 betas [here](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/) and try it out but then you might have to deal with syntax troubles with the rest of your code.

Comment: oh my, tunnel vision. I forgot to check the requirements my xcode version is lower than 7.0 thanks!